# Are there any portable Cloud APIs that allow you to easily change cloud hosts?

Tags: api, scalability, amazon-ec2, storage, cloud

I am creating a web-based RESTful service and want to cloud-enable it for scalability.

I don't want to get locked into one cloud provider though.  I'd like to be able to switched between Go Grid or Amazon EC2, etc. as pricing and needs evolve.

Is there a common API to control the launch, monitoring and shutdown of cloud resources?

I've seen Right Scale, but their pricing is just from another planet.

Similarly, is there a common API for cloud storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [libcloud](http://incubator.apache.org/libcloud/)

Comment: That is exactly what I was hoping to find.  Would have preferred PHP, but Python will do too!  Thank you jdigital!

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with scala or java, you can also check jclouds(http://groups.google.com/group/jclouds)

Answer (score 2):

For Java there is:

- [typica](http://code.google.com/p/typica/)
- [jclouds](http://code.google.com/p/jclouds/)
- [Dasein](http://dasein-cloud.sourceforge.net/)
- [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/)

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you looking an API for? Our SecureBlackbox product offers [CloudBlackbox package](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-cloud.php) of components for uniform access to various cloud storages. Currently supported are S3 and Azure and Google (API for other services is possible on demand).

We don't have uniform API for computational functionality (at least at the moment).